# make menuconfig excuting error from ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-01.00.00.03

Tags: linux, kernel

I have Installed libncurses for menuconfig and try to run the command but i am getting an

### Error :

-support/linux-3.14.43+gitAUTOINC+875c69b2c3-g875c69b> make menuconfig
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.

---

*** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.

---

make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2

but I am able to configure for ti-sdk-am335x-evm-06.00.00.00 and run $ make uImage but in case of  ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-01.00.00.03 getting error is as mentioned.

I have tried :

Try the various interfaces for configuring the kernel. 
host$ make menuconfig
host$ make xconfig
host$ make gconfig
I had to run the following to get these to work. 
host$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
host$ sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools
host$ sudo apt-get install libglade2-dev

but it didnt work. 
Thanks

Comment: **sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev** this should have been solved your problem, because that was what you needed. try **sudo apt-get install libncurses5** also, but should be installed.

Comment: I hope your compilation happens in your home folder, if not you need root or sudo. Any way never compile something as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `make menuconfig` in a shell that does not have the cross-compilation environment setup.  That way the menuconfig will use the host's ncurses libraries that @Michi mentions.  I had the same problem while working with Yocto and trying to do an out-of-tree kernel build with a Yocto built SDK (using `populate_sdk`).